# Select2 4.0.3 - Create new tag if no results

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

i'm using Select2 with ajax and autocomplete.
i have an issue when i type something who doesn't exists.
on first example, i search "fr" to see results, and tag is automatically created! if i try to type more chars, i cant because i have a limit to 1 tag... i click on the "clear" button, and i have to write fast, tag is created but autocomplete stay ...

[Test with basic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKlZV.gif)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // example of data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0x8
  $("#marques").select2({
 ajax: {
  url: "/ajax/acmarques",
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250, // or 600, same result
  processResults: function (data) {
   return {
    results: data
   };
  },
 },
 escapeMarkup: function(m) {
  return m;
 },

 createTag: function(item) {
        return {
            id: item.term,
            text: item.term,
        };
    },
 maximumSelectionLength: 1, // only 1 tag is possible
 tags: true,
 //language: "fr",
 allowClear: true,
 placeholder: "Indiquez la marque de la croquette."
});
  
  });
```

```css
#marques {
    width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
</head>
<body>

<div>
<label for="marques">select2 with ajax/autocomplete</label><select id="marques"></select>
</div>
  
 </body>
 </html>
```

2nd screencast is better, but i cant "validate" a new tag who doesn't exists.
i think the best way is to catch ENTER/TAB key with this little code in createTag.

[Test with createtag return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e83lJ.gif)

```js
createTag: function(item) {
// Don't offset to create a tag if there is no @ symbol
if (item.term.indexOf('@') === -1) {
  // Return null to disable tag creation
  return null;
}
    return {
        id: item.term,
        text: item.term,
    };
},
```

Do you have an idea to solve my problem? i try a lot of things found on github and stackoverflow but it often for old versions of select2 .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's wrong, but it works:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var currentSelectId = null;
  // example of data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0x8
  $("#marques").select2({
 ajax: {
  url: "/ajax/acmarques",
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250, // or 600, same result
  processResults: function (data) {
  $(".select2-selection").on('focus', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // maybe useless
   currentSelectId = $(this).closest('div').find('select').attr('id');
  });
   return {
    results: data
   };
  },
 },
 escapeMarkup: function(m) {
  return m;
 },

 createTag: function(item) {
        // select2-search__field is the class of the input who appears when you have the search field
 $('.select2-search__field').bind('keyup', function (e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code==13) { // ENTER ( TAB doesn't work with code==9, i'll looking for that later
      var valSearch = $(this).val();
      //console.log("current select ID:"+currentSelectId);
      $("#"+currentSelectId).prepend("<option value='"+valSearch+"' selected>"+valSearch+"</option>");
   $("#"+currentSelectId).trigger('change');
   $("#"+currentSelectId).select2('close');
   currentSelectId = null; // reinit
  }
 });
    // Don't offset to create a tag if there is no @ symbol
    if (item.term.indexOf('@') === -1) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return null;
    }
        return {
            id: item.term,
            text: item.term,
        };
    },
 maximumSelectionLength: 1, // only 1 tag is possible
 tags: true,
 //language: "fr",
 allowClear: true,
 placeholder: "Indiquez la marque de la croquette."
});
  
  });
```